# MSAL requires user consent on every login for WPF Desktop Application

Tags: c#, wpf, authentication, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-msal

I am using MSAL.NET library in WPF application for acquiring access token for MSA accounts using interactive token acquisition workflow. The following is the relevant piece of code for token acquisition:

```
PublicClientApplication PublicClientApp = new PublicClientApplication("The-Application-Id", "https://login.microsoftonline.com/consumers/", TokenCacheHelper.GetUserCache());
var authResult = await publicClientApplication.AcquireTokenAsync(new string[] { "email" });
```

where TokenCacheHelper is taken from the [documentation](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-dotnet/wiki/token-cache-serialization). This works fine and I am able to get the access token and ID token in the result. But if the next time I sign in using the same account, again I am required to provide consent for profile and email scopes. Regardless of the number of times I login and provide consent, it is still asking me for consent. I checked my current status on account.live and it says the consent is already provided for the above application. I have gone through multiple documentations but no luck. Can someone provide any pointers?

[image: Image describing repeated consent prompt for same user]

P.S. The above is a converged application that supports native and the reason I am not using AcquireTokenSilentAsync is because I want multiple MSA accounts being able to login on the application installed on the same device.

**Edit**: I tried using the PublicClientApplication without a token cache (thus using the library default) and still the same behavior is observed. To further understand the behavior, I captured the Fiddler trace during MSA login using MSAL. From the below trace, calls to /Consent/Update are observed which is what is causing the consent to be requested on every login. Any idea how to turn this off?

[image]

Comment: It's strange. As per [this](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-dotnet/blob/master/src/Microsoft.Identity.Client/PublicClientApplication.cs) the default `UIBehavior` will be `SelectAccount`. Can you try using `AcquireTokenAsync(IEnumerable<String>, String, UIBehavior, String)` and explicitly pass `UIBehavior` as `SelectAccount` and check?

Comment: Yes, it's indeed strange. I tried with UIBehavior as SelectAccount but still after entering the login information the user is required to consent. Also, I decompiled the code and saw that the default UI behaviour is Select Account.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The developers and POs from MSA team confirmed that this is expected behavior. They [updated](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-dotnet/wiki/Acquiring-tokens-interactively#microsoft-personal-account-require-re-consenting-each-time-the-app-is-run) the documentation to reflect this information. Here is the relevant section from the document:

[image]

To summarize, if your users are using the application with one MSA account per device, then the recommended MSAL usage pattern would ensure that consent is asked to the user just once [unless the cache gets deleted somehow]. If your users operate via multiple MSA accounts per device, then you can leverage the Public Client Application (instantiated using the existing token cache) to get the list of MSA accounts for which the token is cached. Using a custom UI, you could provide the list of accounts to the user and based on his/her selection, get the access token silently thereby preventing the consent screen. Please note that consent can be subdued only as long as the token cache remains. Deletion of the token cache file will force the user to re-login with consent.